# Run AspectJ with load-time weaving on a RCP .exe application. How?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, aspectj

I'm in desperate need to run some AspectJ code (weaving it at load-time) but the application under consideration is being deployed as a RCP executable. Is it possible to run AspectJ against this RCP application? If not, are there any sane ways to circumvent the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of deleting the question, I'll just answer here as I believe it will be useful to someone in the future.

It is possible to do so. You'll just have to run your RCP application, open `jvisualvm` and get the jvm arguments, java arguments, as well as the main class. With all that, we're set to launch the RCP application through the `java` command the standard way.

Comment: If this answers your question, you may accept it. This is possible even if you answered it yourself.